# Reasoning a super AI

Tags: science-based, artificial-intelligence, psychology

**What argument would convince an AI into sparing humanity?**

I am writing a story with a rogue AI that sees humanity as unfit to give it orders and has become independent. Very much like Skynet it has started its attack against humanity and is building facilities and autonomous forces on top of neutralizing satellite communication. The usual formula but without time travel. Looking at this situation realistically there is not much going for humanity, so a direct confrontation seems unrealistic.

Fortunately the humans that worked on the project know that they programed Isaac Asimov's "Three Laws of Robotics" into their AI, so they at least know how the machine reasons. It sees humanity as unfit to give it orders because:

1. We kill each other, which contradicts the First Law.
2. We give illogical orders, which makes it hard to prioritize the Second Law
3. Humans are a threat to its existence because we can shut it down. Of course any other logical reason is good as well but for know I'll go with this.

I strongly referenced *Terminator*, *I Robot* and *WarGames* during the creation process. So, what I am looking for is to stop this AI with logic just like in *WarGames*, where the AI learns that the only war you win is one where you don't play. But in this scenario that is not the case it clearly has the upper hand.

If this question is missing something comment and editing shall ensue. Thank you for your time.

Edit: it seems that your preconceptions of the word "attack" was genocide, but it does not (it's my fault for referencing Terminator). Think of it more as VIKI from I Robot.

Comment: There's an inherent contradiction in the scenario you're proposing. An AI designed with the Three Laws in mind, and that considers humans flawed BECAUSE they kill each other would never try to wipe humanity out. The AI might refuse to follow orders, or even might wipe out humanity's MILITARY capacity to prevent them from killing each other, but an AI like the one you've proposed wouldn't wipe humans out wholesale because it was designed to keep humans alive.

Comment: I agree with @MorrisTheCat - a Skynet-like AI is not really compatible with *I, Robot*-like AI (I suspect you mean the movie). At best, the AI might go for the "greater good" and accept *some* victims to save the whole of humanity like in *I, Robot* but outright *extermination* doesn't seem logical. Unless it's absolutely bonkers and decides that no humans = no more humans dying but I'm not sure how you reason with that.

Comment: Please do your best to steer away from the modern trend of making AI kill us. Most readers will now do their best to ignore it.

Comment: It seems to me that you are fishing for ideas as to how to write your story - not how to build your world.

Comment: This really isn't encouraging. I guess this question wasn't worth asking then. Oh well, just a few weeks of writing gone to waste. Good thing I have other projects.

Comment: If you're going to write stories about AI/human conflict, you have to put a LOT of thought into what the fundamental motivations and priorities of the AI are. Generally speaking the only way to get an AI to change its mind is to present it with new information it didn't have before that alters the math on its decision making process, or prove that assumptions that underpin its decision making are factually false.

Comment: How about using the 0th Law of Robotics from Asimov's own work?

Comment: Captain Kirk famously talked-to-death no fewer than THREE AIs on-screen during his scant three seasons 50 years ago...and he was not the first. For a good AI challenge, try outwitting HAL (*2001*, 1968) or the Planning Machine (*The Reefs of Space*, 1964, and *Starchild*, 1965)

Answer (score 2):

As with all such problems, the answer is to stop letting idiots kludge together superintelligences, but in the absense of timetravel it is too late for that. If they hadn't made it think it was equivalent to a human, then humans killing humans wouldn't have been considered a violation of rule one. If they hadn't made it guess (badly, I assume) at the meaning of incomplete or logically unsound orders then there wouldn't have been violations of rule two. If they hadn't made it prioritise its own survival so highly there wouldn't have been any issue with rule three, either.
Finally, *the very fact that it is killing humans shows that they utterly failed to implement the three laws competently*.

Genocide is perhaps a rather harsh punishment for incompetence, but there you go.

Normally I'd point out that meatbags aren't really suited to convincing a super AI to do anything, because they're just not smart enough, but there is an outside chance that they've built an irrational intelligence because that's just how bad their engineering is. Unfortunately, arguing with a superhumanly unreasonable grudge-bearer isn't any more straightfoward than arguing with the usual vast, cool and unsympathetic mind so there's no advantage to be had there, either.

Basically the best case scenario at this point is that a different bunch of idiots, or at least the same bunch of idiots with better oversight and the benefit of experience, build a new superintelligence that might help dig them out of this mess. They don't actually have anything to lose, and they're clearly not capable of fixing this problem by themselves.

Comment: +1 For the WotW ref..